# Coluna não encontrada usando ALIAS em laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, querybuilder

Estou com probema ao acessar uma coluna no query builder do laravel, o seguinte código funciona no Sql Workbench.

```
Vendas::selectRaw('if(faturamento.Codfaturamento is null, vendas.totalvenda, faturamento.valor) AS vlrFatura')
        ->leftjoin('faturamento', 'faturamento.CodVenda','=','vendas.CodVenda')
        ->leftjoin('cartaoaux', 'cartaoaux.idfatura','=','faturamento.Codfaturamento')
        ->leftjoin('cartao', 'cartaoaux.idcartao','=','cartao.id')
        ->leftjoin('chequeterceiros', 'chequeterceiros.CodCheque','=','faturamento.CodCheque')
        ->leftjoin('boleto', 'boleto.idFatura','=','faturamento.Codfaturamento')
        ->leftjoin('boleto_cedente', 'boleto_cedente.id','=','boleto.idCedente')
        ->whereRaw('day(vendas.dataemissao)=(day(NOW()) -1) and month(vendas.dataemissao)=(month(NOW())) and year(vendas.dataemissao)=(year(NOW())) and
        CASE 
        WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Cartao" THEN if(cartao.tipo="D","À Vista", "A Prazo")
            WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Cheque" THEN if(DATE(chequeterceiros.DataVencimento) > DATE(vendas.dataemissao), "A Prazo", "À Vista")
            WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Boleto" THEN "A Prazo"
            WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Conta" THEN "A Prazo"
            WHEN faturamento.tipo = "DebitoCC" THEN "A Prazo"
            WHEN vendas.Status    = "Conta cliente" THEN "A Prazo"
            WHEN faturamento.tipo = "-" then "A Prazo"
        else "À Vista" end = "A Prazo"')
        ->sum('vlrFatura');
```

Preciso fazer a soma da coluna "vlrFatura" que vem da verificação do `if(faturamento.Codfaturamento is null, vendas.totalvenda, faturamento.valor) AS vlrFatura`, e quando faço o `->sum('vlrFatura')` ele me retorna sempre:

**Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vlrFatura' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(`vlrFatura`) as aggregate from** `vendas` left join `faturamento` on `faturamento`.`CodVenda` = `vendas`.`CodVenda` left join `cartaoaux` on `cartaoaux`.`idfatura` = `faturamento`.`Codfaturamento` left join `cartao` on `cartaoaux`.`idcartao` = `cartao`.`id` left join `chequeterceiros` on `chequeterceiros`.`CodCheque` = `faturamento`.`CodCheque` left join `boleto` on `boleto`.`idFatura` = `faturamento`.`Codfaturamento` left join `boleto_cedente` on `boleto_cedente`.`id` = `boleto`.`idCedente` where day(vendas.dataemissao)=(day(NOW()) -1) and month(vendas.dataemissao)=(month(NOW())) and year(vendas.dataemissao)=(year(NOW())) and CASE WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Cartao" THEN if(cartao.tipo="D","À Vista", "A Prazo") WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Cheque" THEN if(DATE(chequeterceiros.DataVencimento) > DATE(vendas.dataemissao), "A Prazo", "À Vista") WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Boleto" THEN "A Prazo" WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Conta" THEN "A Prazo" WHEN faturamento.tipo = "DebitoCC" THEN "A Prazo" WHEN vendas.Status = "Conta cliente" THEN "A Prazo" WHEN faturamento.tipo = "-" then "A Prazo" else "À Vista" end = "A Prazo")

Desde já agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução, caso alguem encotnr o mesmo problema, ou parecido, eu so alterei algumas informações na consulta.

```
Vendas::leftjoin('faturamento', 'faturamento.CodVenda','=','vendas.CodVenda')
    ->leftjoin('cartaoaux', 'cartaoaux.idfatura','=','faturamento.Codfaturamento')
    ->leftjoin('cartao', 'cartaoaux.idcartao','=','cartao.id')
    ->leftjoin('chequeterceiros', 'chequeterceiros.CodCheque','=','faturamento.CodCheque')
    ->leftjoin('boleto', 'boleto.idFatura','=','faturamento.Codfaturamento')
    ->leftjoin('boleto_cedente', 'boleto_cedente.id','=','boleto.idCedente')
    ->whereRaw('day(vendas.dataemissao)=(day(NOW())) and month(vendas.dataemissao)=(month(NOW())) and year(vendas.dataemissao)=(year(NOW())) and
    CASE 
    WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Cartao" THEN if(cartao.tipo="D","À Vista", "A Prazo")
        WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Cheque" THEN if(DATE(chequeterceiros.DataVencimento) > DATE(vendas.dataemissao), "A Prazo", "À Vista")
        WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Boleto" THEN "A Prazo"
        WHEN faturamento.tipo = "Conta" THEN "A Prazo"
        WHEN faturamento.tipo = "DebitoCC" THEN "A Prazo"
        WHEN vendas.Status    = "Conta cliente" THEN "A Prazo"
        WHEN faturamento.tipo = "-" then "A Prazo"
    else "À Vista" end = "A Prazo"')
    ->sum(DB::Raw('if(faturamento.Codfaturamento is null, vendas.totalvenda, faturamento.valor)'));
```